# Don't run query if parameter is null

Tags: reactjs, graphql, strapi

I would like to ask for your guidance, with regards to this GraphQL query.
I would like it to check if the query parameter is null and not to fire the query.
Currently despite the fact that the query is null, it retrieves all the data, which means that we use some computational power unnecessary.

```
const search_reviews= gql`
 query SearchReviews ($my_query: String) {
    reviews (filters: {or: [{body: {contains: $my_query} }, {title: {contains: $my_query}}]}) {
      data{
        id
        attributes{
          title
          rating
          body
          categories{
            data{
              id
              attributes
              {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
  
 }
}

`
```

And the code from React

```
const [ first, setFirst ] = useState(false)
    const [ query, setQuery] = useState("")

    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(search_reviews, {variables: {my_query: query}})
    if (loading) return <p>Loading data...</p>
    if (error) return <p>Error fetching data</p>
    console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the answer:

```
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(search_reviews, {skip: !first,variables: {my_query: query}})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `skip` key of `useQuery` hook options to achieve this:

```
const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(SEARCH_REVIEWS, {
  variables: /* snip */,
  skip: !param,
});
```